# How to print a very wide web page?

Tags: html, printing

I have built a table in HTML that can become very wide (i.e. showing 365 days in individual columns).  This table is viewable in the browser by scrolling left/right.
However, to print this table or export to PDF, the browser chops off everything to the right of the first page.

The page uses Bootstrap 3 library, in case this may be inhibiting the wide printing.

Any ideas on how to prevent the browser from cropping off the width?  (It doesn't crop height - if the page is very tall it breaks the table into multiple pages, but each is cut off at page width.)

Note that I can scale the output to around 10% and fit the entire table on one page, but it's so small it's unreadable.

Comment: First of all, you can add custom styles for printing using @media print { ... } in your stylesheet. However, you should be more clear in what you want to achieve. If scaling to page size makes the font too small to read, you may either have to reconsider your layout or to split your table to multiple pages.

Comment: unfortunately the only solution I see for that kind of problem is rotating the content so that it will spread vertically instead of horizontally. But yet you have rows so the same problem will remain on the other dimension. What could be done is `transform:rotate(90deg);` over the table (adjusting the margin top according to its height) but printing only a small subset of rows each time. That's all I can think of

Comment: The issue is that the browser cuts off the wide portion instead of dividing it into multiple pages. I want to leave scaling at 100%, but have the wide portion broken into pages.